# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Command Prompt Truncates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, command-prompt, truncate

When I print out my results in C++ (multiple, multiple lines are printed) my output gets truncated by the command prompt attached to Visual Studio. I tried changing my buffer size via the OS preferences, but it seems as though VS has their own settings. I have tried finding the answer to this problem to no avail. If anyone can help out it would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you don't show us how you "print out" your results in C++, how are we supposed to be able to help?

Comment: Redirect the output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Set the preferences on the Visual Studio 2013 debug window, not on the command prompt window. Windows remembers console preferences based on the executed executable.